# sci-fi book where kids are sent on a suicide mission to a black hole?

Tags: story-identification

A book was recommend to me by a friend, and I forgot what it was called, but it sounded cool. Several kids are sent on a spaceship to travel inside a black hole. They have devices hooked up to their brains that are so that the scientists on earth can connect to their brains to see what's going on. My friend wouldn't tell me any more than this (didn't want to spoil it).

Comment: I'm sorry I post so many story ID questions. I have this list in my head of books that I need to read, then I forget them before I can write them down.

Comment: Could you not ask your friend?

Comment: he doesn't use social media, i only see him at local comicons, and things like that.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter: If you ever do get a chance to check in with your friend...